# Selection sort of singly Linked Lists by swapping nodes(iterative approach)?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, selection-sort

***I am trying to perform selection sort on singly linked list by swapping the node itself but after all the inputs it looks like my sort() function in not working properly.
What am I missing or did wrong please someone help me with that.***

**NOTE: Name of all the functions and pointers pretty much tells their task so I thought not to add comments But if anyone wants comment then please let me know.**

**NOTE: In `swap_node(int i, int j)`,`i` and `j` are the positions of the two nodes which needs to be swapped.**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *head = NULL, *prev = NULL, *next = NULL;

static int k = 0;//Global variable K which will store the no of nodes created so far.

node *make_node()
{
    k++;
    return ((node *)malloc(sizeof(node)));
}

void push()
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        next = make_node();
        printf("Enter Data:");
        scanf("%d", &next->data);
        next->next = NULL;
        head = next;
        prev = next;
    }
    else
    {
        next = make_node();
        printf("Enter Data:");
        scanf("%d", &next->data);
        next->next = NULL;
        prev->next = next;
        prev = next;
    }
}

node *x = NULL, *y = NULL;

void swap_node(int i, int j)
{
    node *prevX = NULL, *currX = head, *prevY = NULL, *currY = head;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        for (int l = 1; l < j; l++)
        {
            prevY = currY;
            currY = currY->next;
        }
        head = currY;
        if (j - i == 1)
        {
            currX->next = currY->next;
            currY->next = currX;
        }
        else
        {
            node *temp = currX->next;
            currX->next = currY->next;
            currY->next = temp;
            prevY->next = currX;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int l = 1; l < i; l++)
        {
            prevX = currX;
            currX = currX->next;
        }
        for (int l = 1; l < j; l++)
        {
            prevY = currY;
            currY = currY->next;
        }
        if (j - i == 1)
        {
            prevX->next = currY;
            currX->next = currY->next;
            currY->next = currX;
        }
        else
        {
            node *temp = currX->next;
            prevX->next = currY;
            prevY->next = currX;
            currX->next = currY->next;
            currY->next = temp;
        }
    }
    x = currX;
    y = currY;
}

void sort()
{
    x = head;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        y = x->next;
        for (j = i + 1; j <= k; j++)
        {
            if (x->data > y->data)
            {
                swap_node(i, j);
            }
            y = y->next;
        }
        x = x->next;
    }
}

void print_node()
{
    printf("------------Printing Node--------------\n");
    node *temp = head;
    do
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != NULL);
}

void main(void)
{
    int choice;
    printf("MENU\n1-PUSH\n2-Print node\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Enter Your Choice:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            sort();
            print_node();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong Choice!");
        }

    } while (choice == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just swap the content :

```
void swap_content (node *first, node *second) {
    int med = first->data; 
    first->data = second->data;
    second->data = med;
}
```

Comment: This is another possibility but I want to swap the nodes and not the contents.